# Group BY Statement error to get unique records

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am new to SQL Server, used to work with MYSQL and trying to get the records from a table using Group By.

The table structure is given below:

```
SELECT S1.ID,S1.Template_ID,S1.Assigned_By,S1.Assignees,S1.Active FROM "Schedule" AS S1;
```

Output:

```
ID Template_ID  Assigned_By Assignees Active
2   25          1           3         1
3   25          5           6         1
6   26          5           6         1
```

I need to get the values of all columns using the Group By statement below

```
SELECT Template_ID FROM "Schedule" WHERE "Assignees" IN(6, 3) GROUP BY "Template_ID";
```

Output:

```
Template_ID

25
26
```

I tried the following code to fetch the table using Group By, but it's fetching all the rows.

```
SELECT S1.ID,S1.Template_ID,S1.Assigned_By,S1.Assignees,S1.Active FROM "Schedule" AS S1 INNER JOIN(SELECT Template_ID FROM "Schedule" WHERE "Assignees" IN(6, 3) GROUP BY "Template_ID") AS S2 ON S2.Template_ID=S1.Template_ID
```

My Output Should be like,

```
   ID Template_ID  Assigned_By Assignees Active
    2   25          1           3         1
    6   26          5           6         1
```

I was wondering whether I can get ID of the column as well? I use the ID for editing the records in the web.

Comment: The query you ask for is [invalid even in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). What you though worked is *unsupported* syntax that throws an error in recent versions and returns random results in earlier versions - there's no implicit order in a table or query unless specified by `ORDER BY` so the server will return the first value returned by the query's execution.

Comment: MySql didn't have issues with GroupBy. I am trying to figure out how SQL retrieve IDs using Group By

Comment: yes it does, and I just posted the link to [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) that explains this. You used an unsupported hack. You had a bad query before, that would throw in MySQL 5.7. it's still a bad query in SQL Server, or any other database. In older MySQL versions you'd get random values instead of the first row

Comment: `group by` is for aggregation, I think you want to use a [window function](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/) to get the row number and take the first row for each template_id?

Comment: @DaleBurrell yes. I had the aggregation error and then I tried this query

Comment: @Zendie what do you want to do? Why do you want to use GROUP BY if you want to return all columns? Even in MySQL, the supported way is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` or one of the other ranking functions introduced in MySQL 8.0

Comment: @Zendie you should be aware that since this is unsupported, MySQL doesn't test its behaviour. Queries with nonaggregated columns perform far worse in MySQL 5.7 than they did in earlier versions

Comment: @Zendie from the [5.6 docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) `The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic.`

Comment: I want to to return only one row from the table where the user belongs to a group(that is Assignees)

Comment: @Zendie only one row based on what criteria? Random? Smallest ID?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  SELECT Template_ID FROM "Schedule" WHERE "Assignees" IN(6, 3) GROUP BY "Template_ID"; This is exactly what I want to do, but I need other column values as well with this result. Smallest ID will display

Comment: If Template_ID = 25 that matches 2 rows, but you only want to display one row, but you want to display all values. Do you see why we are confused? If you want to display all values without aggregation, you have to pick a row.

Comment: We suspect you want to pick the row with the lowest id, in which case the answer is a window function, which I linked to in an earlier comment.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Thanks you I will have a look at window function. I need to group by the records by TemplateID. And need to display the values of lowest ID,assigned by and active value

Comment: If you want to group by and show the lowest values just use the `min` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query doesn't work as expected in MySQL either, except by accident.

Nonaggregated columns in MySQL aren't part of the SQL standard and [not even allowed in MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and later unless the default value of the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode is changed.

In earlier versions the result [is non-deterministic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.

This means there's was no way to know what rows will be returned this query :

```
SELECT S1.ID,S1.Template_ID,S1.Assigned_By,S1.Assignees,S1.Active 
FROM "Schedule" AS S1
GROUP BY Template_ID;
```

To get deterministic results you'd need a way to rank rows with the [ranking functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) introduced in MySQL 8, like `ROW_NUMBER()`. These are already [available in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) since SQL Server 2012 at least. The syntax is the same for both databases :

```
WITH ranked as AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ID,Template_ID,Assigned_By,Assignees Active, 
        ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY Template_ID Order BY ID)
    FROM Scheduled
    WHERE Assignees IN(6, 3) 
)
SELECT ID,Template_ID,Assigned_By,Assignees Active
FROM ranked
Where RN=1
```

`PARTITION BY Template_ID` splits the result rows based on their `Template_ID` value into separate partitions. Within that partition, the rows are ordered based on the `ORDER BY` clause. Finally, `ROW_NUMBER` calculates a row number for each ordered partition row.